# Saying fraction with a noun

Tags: comparative-constructions

Consider a sentence like

> We consider a cluster only if the size of the cluster is at least 1/k of the size of its parent.

How can we reword the sentence with a fraction + noun. Maybe something like this:

> We consider a cluster only if it has at least 1/k vertices of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

> We consider a cluster only if it has at least 1/k vertices of its parent.

This sentence is only valid if the cluster and the parent share some vertices (for example, two cubes of different sizes could share only one vertex), and we are saying that the cluster shares 1/k of the parent's vertices.

If the cluster and its parent do no share any vertices and you are simply concerned about the relative **number** of vertices of cluster and parent, you should write:

> We consider a cluster only if it has at least 1/k **of the number of** vertices of its parent.